# GCSToBigQueryOperator not working in composer-2.1.0-airflow-2.3.4

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

After a recent upgrade to composer-2.1.0-airflow-2.3.4 the GCSToBigQueryOperator is no longer able to find data in buckets to upload to BigQuery.

All other aspects of the DAGs still work.

The usage is as follows

```py
    gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id                             = f"transfer_{data_type}_to_bq_task",
        bucket                              = os.environ["GCS_BUCKET"],
        source_objects                      = file_names,
        destination_project_dataset_table   = os.environ["GCP_PROJECT"] + f".creditsafe.{data_type}",
        schema_object                       = f"dags/schema/creditsafe/{data_type}.json",
        source_format                       = "CSV",
        field_delimiter                     = '|',
        quote_character                     = "",
        max_bad_records                     = 0,
        create_disposition                  = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        ignore_unknown_values               = True,
        allow_quoted_newlines               = True,
        allow_jagged_rows                   = True,
        write_disposition                   = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        gcp_conn_id                         = 'google_cloud_default',
        skip_leading_rows                   = 1,
        dag                                 = dag
    )
```

The error from the API is

```json
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET

{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Unknown output format: media:", "errors": [ { "message": "Unknown output format: media:", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalidAltValue", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "alt" } ] } }
```

The error delivered by Cloud Composer is

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_HIDDEN]/o/data%2Fcreditsafe%2FCD01%2Ftxt%2F%2A.txt?alt=media: No such object: [BUCKET_HIDDEN]/data/creditsafe/CD01/txt/*.txt: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

I can't see the cause of the error. The reference to the GCS location has not changed and appears correct while the `gcp_conn_id` appears sufficient for all other tasks. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hi @David Kane, can you  clarify how you are defining `GCS_BUCKET`?

Comment: I don't. It is provided automatically by Cloud Composer. It is the name of the bucket used by Cloud Composer. This is the bucket that includes the DAG and the data folders.

Comment: I've done some more digging and the issue is the use of the wildcard which no longer works after the upgrade. If I select a single file everything works as before.

The wildcard is hidden in the code, but I can make "file_names" reference a single file, or use a wildcard operator.

Comment: Hi @David Kane, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCSToBigQueryOperator does not support wildcard *.csv. For your requirement, you can try the below steps:

- You can attach to a pod in the composer environment by running the below commands :

1. `gcloud container clusters get-credentials --region __GCP_REGION__ __GKE_CLUSTER_NAME__`
2. `kubectl get pods -n [Namespace]`
3. `kubectl exec -it [Worker] -n [Namespace] -- bash`

- You can run the below command to identify the google provider package,

  `pip list | grep -i goo | grep provider`

  If the output of the above command is a different version from 8.3.0 then change the version to apache-airflow-providers-google ==8.3.0.

Comment: Thanks, we are not really able to implement your solution as it would involve python package spaghetti.

However, your answer is correct and a number of other users have encountered the same breaking change. I am no longer willing to use Airflow and will code directly using the Google Python libraries using more modern serverless tools.

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this above issue has now been made

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28444

It is unclear how long it will take for this to be integrated into the Cloud Composer libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The release 8.5.0 of apache-airflow-providers-google that cames with airflow (>2.3.4 and <2.5.1) introduced several critical regressions nottably:

- GCSToBigquery operator is broken as it ignores its options https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/27961
  This means that all custom settings specified in the operator (delimiter, formatting, null values, wildcards on files) are no longer sent to BigQuery leading to unexpected results.

Until Google releases a composer version based on airflow 2.5.1 the workaround is to upgrade the apache-airflow-providers-google  library (or to use a composer version based on apache <=2.2.5).

No need to connect via gcloud/kubectl to change the apache-airflow-providers-google version, you can change it directly in the Composer UI, via PyPi Packages page (or via the terraform provider).

I can confirm that on the latest (today) composer : composer-1.20.4-airflow-2.4.3 configuring the apache-airflow-providers-google ==8.8.0  (latest) solves those issues for me.

But as mentioned previously this is only an workaround and your mileage might vary...

[configuring custom PyPI packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kExnw.png)